# Rails 3.2.11 app (with mongoid/MongoHQ) crashes on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid

I am using Rails 3.2.11 and it works locally with mongoid on a local mongodb. I have provisioned MongoHQ and set mongoid.yml correctly. Soon after app is deployed it fails on starting a web dyno as if rails server is not a valid command!

```
    2013-03-22T00:13:33+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 5052`
    2013-03-22T00:16:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage:
    2013-03-22T00:16:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   rails new APP_PATH [options]
    2013-03-22T00:16:59+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2013-03-22T00:16:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Options:
    ...
```

I tried running this bundle exec as a one-off command and it gives the same error.
I am specifying ruby 1.9.3 in Gemfile.
Unicorn starts but on the browser it says "Application Error" with nothing logged into unicorn.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I have just figured out that I didn't git add script/rails! Fixed.